# Can Windows 10 on BitLocker dual-boot with Ubuntu on LUKS?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bitlocker, secure-boot

Good afternoon all,
I would like to ask if having a dual boot system of Windows 10 and Ubuntu is possible with the features below activated.

- Secure boot
- UEFI
- TPM
- BitLocker
- Hyper-V with the security features it enables
- LUKS encryption with LVM for Ubuntu

Will installing Ubuntu affect BitLocker and trigger recovery? The system will have fresh installs of both operating systems so there is no worry of data loss currently.

Will it be stable also, so if I upgrade either Windows or Ubuntu it won't break the other?

Comment: Ubuntu and Bitlocker do not play well together.

Comment: Windows do not play well together with LUKS.  The rest of your criteria isn't an issue, except perhaps Secure Boot, depending which Ubuntu release you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but I would not recommend it. I've had such a dual-boot dual-encrypted system with Bitlocker for Windows 10 (encrypted system drive and encrypted data drive) and Ubuntu 22.04 (unencrypted boot, LUKS-encrypted root and swap) for the past 8 months. Installation was a major effort with many retries from scratch and from backups. This has taken multiple days.

Only rarely during regular usage, Windows has asked for the Bitlocker recovery key to be entered, and after that it has always returned to unlocking from TPM. For LUKS, I have always entered the passphrase manually on boot.

The system has finally died today because Windows has somehow changed the boot process so that Windows boots directly and I no longer see grub. After spending some hours trying to repair the dual-boot dual-encrypted system without success, I will now give up on this.

My recommendation if you need to encrypt both systems is to install only one system on the hardware and to install the other system in a VM inside the first system. My reasoning is that you cannot prevent Windows from tampering with the boot process and when it does, it may happen at a too inconvenient time.